# Excel hyperlink to html with fragment identifier does not work

Tags: html, excel

I want a cell in an Excel spreadsheet to link to an HTML document using a URL with a fragment identifier (i.e., hash-mark, followed by an identifier that is the value of a name attribute in an anchor element:  'MyDoc.html#MyFragmentIdentifier').

I've tried using both the Insert Hyperlink dialog and the HYPERLINK function.  In both cases, the fragment identifier is ignored;  the HTML document opens at the top, but does not scroll to the named identifier.  In fact, the identifier does not appear in the address bar of the web browser -- just the address of the page -- so I assume that the fragment identifier is never passed to the browser in the first place.

I've set my default browser to Chrome, IE, and Firefox, all to no avail -- the same behavior in all cases.

Is there a way to coerce Excel into opening the browser correctly?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the hyperlink with right-click, Hyperlink you set the 'friendly name' in `Text to display:` then the URL down to the page in `Address:`. Finally you click <kbd>Bookmark</kbd> and let the **Insert Hyperlink** wizard resolve the address and give you a list of the bookmarks.

The Insert Hyperlink wizard has trouble resolving the bookmarks from some pages; notably dynamic content or content behind a username/password. In these case, the link can be created in VBA via the `.Hyperlink.Add` method's `Address:=<url>` and `.SubAddress:=<page bookmark` parameters.

Comment: Thanks, Jeeped.  I'm using Ruby and win32ole, and so am already generating the links programatically.  I changed the code to use the SubAddress property (instead of an all-in-one Address), which is cleaner, but did not change the behavior.  The link in Excel is correct, but the html doc opens still at the top.

Comment: @BurdetteLamar - What is the URl and the `name=<bookmark>` that you are trying to hit?

Comment: The URI points to an html file local to the spreadsheet, so you won't be able to inspect it, if that's what you have in mind.  Basically, it's C:\Users\Burdette.Lamar\Documents\<whatever>#<my_fragment_id>.

Comment: @BurdetteLamar - As you are not editing your original question to include the HTML that defines the name, it is hard to proceed. My only suggestion would be to use the name attribute in the `SubAddress:=...` parameter and *not* include the hashmark (e.g. #); a common mistake. I've also seen problems with names that are used more than once within a single HTML document.

Comment: I am using the SubAddress attribute, and can also see that the hyperlink address in Excel does not contain more than one hash character.  I'm pretty sure the problem is in Excel, because the URL seen in the browser after following the link does not contain #frag_id, which I think means that Excel did not emit it.  That seems to me like an Excel bug.  The name is definitely not repeated in the html.  There are also internal links in the html (including ones to the very fragment in question) that do work.  Finally, if I manually add the #frag_id after following the link, that also works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem with hyperlinks containing "#" arises when Excel creates hyperlinks, but I was able to get around this by modifying an existing hashmark-containing hyperlink inside Excel's Object model.  Doing this automatically, try this:

```
Sub Make_Column_A_into_hyperlinks_hashmarkworkaround()

'Column "A" contains the text of links to some files.
'This subroutine will turn those cells into Excel hyperlinks...
'...and then correct the hyperlinks in case Excel misinterpreted
'a # mark which had originally occurred in the filename.
'Because I'm using selection.End(xlDown).Select to find the complete list,
'this program does not tolerate any blanks in the "A" column list.
'Note that I don't add a hyperlink in Row 1.

Dim A As Object
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim Height As Long

With ActiveSheet
.Cells(1, 1).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Height = Selection.Row

For lngRow = 2 To Height
.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveSheet.Cells(lngRow, 2), Address:=Chr(34) & ActiveSheet.Cells(lngRow, 1).Value & Chr(34), TextToDisplay:="Open", _
ScreenTip:=Chr(34) & ActiveSheet.Cells(lngRow, 1).Value & Chr(34)
Next

For Each A In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks

If A.ScreenTip <> "" Then
If InStr(1, A.ScreenTip, "#") <> 0 Then
A.Address = Mid(A.ScreenTip, 2, Len(A.ScreenTip) - 2)
End If
End If

Next
End With

End Sub
```